# How to draw a "Y" shaped branch in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, geometric-transform

I want to draw a Y-shaped branch in Mathematica. I am trying to draw a line of length L. In step II, I want to translate to the ending point of the line. Then I want to rotate at an angle of 45 deg to the right and draw a line of length L*0.66. Then translate back to the ending point of the first line and draw a line to the left by rotating left at an angle of 45deg. I have tried four several hours but got no success. Below is the code which I have tried:

```
    L = 100;
    Graphics[
        line = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -L}}];
        Translate[line, {L/2, L}],
        line = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, - L*0.66}}];
        Rotate[line, -30 Degree]
    ]
```

Comment: The variable `p` is undefined. And after `Graphics`, you want the graphics elements to be enclosed in a `List` or `{..}`

Comment: `Graphics[{Line[{{{0, 0}, {0, -1}}, {{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {-1/2,
       1}}}]}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html), [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) and [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html):

```
line = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -L}}];
Graphics[{line, 
 Scale[#, 2/3, {0, 0}] & /@ 
   (Rotate[Translate[line, {0, L}], # Degree, {0, 0}] & /@ {-30, 30})}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.